# Python 3 загрузка файла по прямой ссылке

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть моя программа с GUI(tkinter) и в коде при нажатии на label реализована скачка файла по прямой ссылке. Проблема в том, что при нажатии программа зависает, пока файл полностью не скачается. Можно ли это как-то пофиксить? Просто я хочу добавить прогрессбар загрузки, а прога виснет.

Comment: Можно. Скачивайте в отдельном потоке, а не в основном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот пример скачивание файлов разными потоками

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Python 2.7 версии

import os
import urllib2
from threading import Thread

class DownloadThread(Thread):
    """
    Пример многопоточной загрузки файлов из интернета
    """

    def __init__(self, url, name):
        """Инициализация потока"""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.url = url

    def run(self):
        """Запуск потока"""
        handle = urllib2.urlopen(self.url)
        fname = os.path.basename(self.url)

        with open(fname, "wb") as f_handler:
            while True:
                chunk = handle.read(1024)
                if not chunk:
                    break
                f_handler.write(chunk)

        msg = "%s закончил загрузку %s!" % (self.name, self.url)
        print(msg)


def main(urls):
    """
    Run the program
    """
    for item, url in enumerate(urls):
        name = "Поток %s" % (item+1)
        thread = DownloadThread(url, name)
        thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls = ["http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf",
            "http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040a.pdf",
            "http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040ez.pdf",
            "http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040es.pdf",
            "http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sb.pdf"]

    main(urls)
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо большое